# What is Google Play Services Multiplayer?

Tags: android, networking, multiplayer, google-play-services

This question might be off-topic, i don't know where should i ask it.

What's the difference between [Google Play Real-Time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer), [Google Play Turn-Based Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer) and sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play's Real Time and Turn-Based multiplayer provide a high-level framework supporting real-time or turn-based multiplayer in your game, respectively. They offer you ways to perform peer-matching and invitation and state updating, as well as providing a pipeline upon which you can build the actual game-specific networking on, if you want.

"Sockets," on the other hand, are a low-level networking concept that allow you to open connections to other devices and transmit arbitrary data back and forth.

Google's services are built *on top of* sockets, and are thus higher-level and easier to use. If you eschew them in favor of using lower-level sockets APIs, you'll be doing a lot more work yourself to re-implement everything Google's services are providing for you.

Comment: I'm making a HTML5 game and planning to port it to android with Cordova. I think i can't use Google's Real Time Multiplayer with Javascript, looks like i have to use websockets :{